# i don't now, why i have error in this sql request

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE `vjprf_jshopping_manufacturers` 
SET `meta_title_en-GB`='Buy products from the manufacturer '.`name_en-GB`.' 
in Ukraine at wholesale prices | Deps' WHERE `manufacturer_id`=3
```

i need to insert the `name_en-GB` in the `meta_title_en-GB`='some text (`place to insert name_en-GB`) some text'

error number #1064

Comment: please add some explanations about your code... Also show the error(s) you get

Comment: Please supply the error that you are getting.

Comment: i need to insert the `name_en-GB` in the 'meta_title_en-GB'='some text (place to insert name_en-GB) some text'

Comment: error number #1064

Comment: Back-ticks and single quotes mix-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot is used for string concatenation in PHP.  Use the `CONCAT` function in MySQL:

```
UPDATE vjprf_jshopping_manufacturers
SET meta_title_en-GB = CONCAT('Buy products from the manufacturer ', name_en-GB,
    ' in Ukraine at wholesale prices | Deps')
WHERE
    manufacturer_id = 3;
```